# Title for student organization

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, names, proper-nouns, titles

I'm updating the website for my student organization. [Link](http://aiaa.tamu.edu/). Officially, we are the Texas A&M University Student Branch of the American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics.

The banner at the top has the title of the national organization, the American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics, and a subtitle describing this organization:

A Professional Society for Aerospace Engineering (a)

1. Shouldn't the P and S be lowercase?

A professional society for Aerospace Engineering (b)

I vaguely remember reading in elementary school that the last word of a title should begin with a capital letter, so Engineering. If engineering is capitalized, then Aerospace should be capitalized as well, otherwise the title would look weird. However, I then feel that the resulting subtitle b looks funny. Is it funny or am I just used to capitalizing letters?

2. Also, which is the correct abbreviation of our title: AIAA-TAMU, TAMU-AIAA, or neither? I would like to learn the rules behind your logic.

--An engineering student who cares about grammar (except for any mistakes in this post. It's late and I'm tired)

Comment: I'd also ask on the outstanding http://aviation.stackexchange.com site, which is one of the best network sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no firm rule**.  Consider looking at a **style book** for your own college. If you don't know what that is, ask someone at, eg., the college newspaper.

Personally I would "A professional society for aerospace engineering" (or indeed aerospace industry) because I loathe excess capitals.

Note that - very simply - there is absolutely no reason, at all, for capitals in that sentence; any more than say this sentence.

A "subtitle" is nothing more than a sentence.

(By all means, you could note that for example, highway billboards often have all caps .. DRINK MILLER BEER. And maybe just a *design* matter it should be all caps. But that's sort of, not English you know, that's a design issue. Like, sure, maybe it should be done in a circle like a stamp ... whatever.)

If it's a sentence, it has no caps.

"I vaguely remember reading in elementary school..." that was complete crap, forget it.

TAMU-AIAA versus AIAA-TAMU. If this is your official name: "Texas A&M University Student Branch of the American Institute of Aeronautics and Astronautics" - official meaning it appears thus on some sort of government document, or any similar "registration" document - then the best choice is exactly that order.

So, TAMU-AIAA.

Comment: Style books! I completely forgot about that. In fact, TAMU rather strictly controls its public image, so I'm sure the publicity office will have an opinion. Thanks!

Comment: What if we replace Aerospace Engineering with Aerospace Industry? Should I still keep A and I capital, or is that a devolution from Aerospace Engineering?

Comment: (I beg your pardon, I made a typo.)  It should be **all lower case**.  It's this extremely simple: there is utterly no reason, at all, for capitals in that sentence. Case closed.  It would be Like If I wrote this sentence like this.  It's "just silly", there's simply no reason for it.

Comment: I agree that the best solution is to look at a style guide or ask publicity office. This subtitle is not in fact a complete sentence, only a noun phrase.

Comment: tech - yes the simple fact is TAMU will have guidelines on this. not unlike with any product; say you are a partner of, oh, Apple, and you use their logo etc ("works with Apple!" sort of thing), there are always careful usage guidelines.  essentially that's the answer here.

Comment: it's fascinating that "corporate language policy" is now becoming an important aspect (for better or worse) of the concept "grammar and spelling and writing questions".

Comment: While you're at it, techSultan, ask the publicity office if it is the official policy for all publications associated with Texas A&M to refer to the University of Texas as "texas university."